# Find the values of $a$ and $b$ / $ f(x) \; \text{is derivable} \; \forall x \in \Bbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Find the values of $a$ and $b$ such that: $$ f(x) = \left\{  \begin{array}{c} \frac{\sin(4x^2 + bx)}{3x} \; \text{if} \; x\gt 0 \\ ax+ 2 \; \text{if} \; x \le0 \end{array} \right. \text{is differentiable} \; \forall x \in \Bbb R$$

$\text{So, what I'm trying to do, is to calculate} \; \frac{d}{dx} f(x)|_{x=0} \; \text{by definition, since it is differentiable} \; \forall \; x \in \Bbb R -\{0\}$

But, to be differentiable, it has to be continuous at that point. So:

$\lim\limits_{x\to 0^{-}} f(x) = \lim\limits_{x\to 0^{-}} \frac{\sin(4x^2 + bx)}{3x} = \frac{b}{3} = \lim\limits_{x\to 0^{+}} f(x) = \lim\limits_{x\to 0^{+}} ax+2 = 2 \; \rightarrow b=6$

$\frac{d}{dx} f(x)|_{x=0} = \lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}$

Let's do first $\lim\limits_{h\to 0^{-}} \frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h} = \lim\limits_{h\to 0^{-}} \frac{ah +2 -2}{h} = \lim\limits_{h\to 0^{-}} \frac{ah}{h} = a$

Secondly  $\lim\limits_{h\to 0^{+}} \frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h} = \lim\limits_{h\to 0^{+}} \Big(\frac{\sin(4h^2 + 6h)}{3h} -2 \Big) \frac{1}{h} = \lim\limits_{h\to 0^{+}} \Big(\frac{\sin(4h^2 + 6h)-6h}{3h^2} \Big)$

Now, I don't know how to proceed, I did the expansion of $\sin(4h^2 + 6h)$ but the 6h in the numerator makes thing difficult for me. Any hints? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

It is clear the function is differentiable at $ (-\infty,0) $ and $ (0, +\infty)$.

Si, we just need differentiability at $ x=0$.

But, before we need continuity.

$$\lim_{0^-}f(x)=\lim_{0^-}(ax+2)=2$$

$$=\lim_{0^+}f(x)=\lim_{0^+}\frac{\sin(4x^2+bx)}{3x}=\frac b3$$

So $ b=6$.

Comment: I edited the post since the function defined for $x \gt 0$ was $ax+2$, not $ax+b$ although It helps your answer, I still can't find the derivate of the function at $x=0$

Comment: @Karl I edited my answer with the new function.

Answer (score 1):

Hint for your limit: write it appropriately using algebra:

$\displaystyle \left(\frac{sin(4h^2+bh)}{3h}-2\right)\times \frac{1}{h}= \frac{sin(4h^2+bh)-6h}{3h^2}$. Since the $\lim_ 0 sin(4h^2+bh)-6h=0$ and $\lim_{0} 3h^2=0$ then we can apply L'Hopital's rule.

Then you need to use both continuity and diferentiability to get a system of 2 equations and 2 unknowns since you have both $a$ and $b$ here.

Hope this helps

Comment: It helps, but I don't use L'Hopital's rule. I was trying to find the limit without it.